# A property of $I$-adic topologies

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with multiplicative identity and $I$ a proper ideal of $R$ such that the intersection of its powers is the zero ideal. It can be shown that if the $I$-adic topology is complete, then $I$ is included in the Jacobson radical $J(R)$. Is the converse true, i.e., if $I$ is included in $J(R)$, is the $I$-adic topology complete?

Comment: Try some simple examples, e.g., a local ring like $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$ for a prime $p$.

Answer (score 3):

Any non-complete local ring will give you a counterexample: if $(R,m)$ is local but not complete, then taking $I = m$, certainly $I \subseteq J(R)$, but $R$ is not $I$-adically complete. Explicitly, you can take $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ (as mentioned in comments) or $k[x]_{(x)}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just have a small question. Can you give me a proof that $Z_{p}$ and $k[x]_{x}$ are not complete in their $m$-adic topologies.

Comment: I should have written $Z_{(p)}$ and $k[x]_{(x)}$

Comment: One way to see that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and $k[x]_{(x)}$ are not complete: if they were, then the natural maps to the $m$-adic completions would be isomorphisms, but we know that the completions are respectively $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $k[[x]]$ (and e.g. these have different quotient fields than their non-complete versions).

Answer (score 2):

Not at all, as other answers have shown, but there is a nice corollary in Serre's book *Local Algebra* which gives more information about the $I$-adic topology induced by an ideal $I\subset J(R)$ in the Jacobson radical of a ring $R$. (This comes at the end of part A of Chapter II.)

> The following are equivalent:
>   (i) $I$ is contained in $J(R)$.
>   (ii) Every finitely generated $R$-module is Hausdorff for the $I$-adic topology.
>   (iii) Every submodule of a finitely generated $R$-module is closed for the $I$-adic topology.

In particular, your starting assumption that the $I$-adic topology on $R$ is Hausdorff (i.e. that $\cap\,I^n=0$) is redundant if $I\subset J(R)$, in view of (ii) above.