# Ideals of zero intersection are in powers of the maximal ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings

let $A$ be a noetherian local ring, with maximal ideal $\frak m$.
I suppose moreover that $A$ is complete for the $\frak m$-adic topology, if that helps.
Let $(I_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a decreasing sequence of ideals of $A$, with $\bigcap I_n=0$.

Do I have : $$\forall k \ge 1, \exists n \ge 1, I_n \subset \mathfrak{m}^k$$
?? (i.e. : if the $I_n$ 'tend' to $0$, are they in each $\mathfrak{m}^k$ ?)
[Edit : I juste noticed that this is nothing but a theorem by Chevalley, lemma 7 in Chevalley, On the theory of local rings, Ann. Math. 44 (4), 1943]

Comment: I saw this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579474/on-descending-chain-of-ideals-with-zero-intersection-in-a-complete-semi-local-ri?noredirect=1&lq=1. However, I don't see why $S' \subset I_n$ holds... for me, it's only $S' \subset I_n + J^{s+1}$

Comment: Take your $S' \subseteq I_n + J^{s+1}$ and look at $S'' := S' \cap I_n$ instead, which is nonzero because $J^{s+1} \subsetneq S'$